# Is there any documentation or advice for a 5 year Greek visa?

Tags: visas, south-africa, greece, long-term

I'm looking to get my 5 year Greek visa, rather than a 1 year one, so that I can travel Europe without returning to South Africa after a year. But Greek embassies give practically nothing away, and every time I go they want me to bring something else. Has anyone gone through the process and can help?

Comment: Are you looking to apply for a tourist / visitor visa? If so, you should bear in mind that you can't "travel Europe" for a year in one go: you're limited to 90 in every 180 days in the Schengen area. A 5 year visa won't help in this regard, it's still only intended for relatively short visits.

Comment: This will probably sound snarky but the fact that you completely misunderstood what you can do on a 1-year visa suggests that you didn't read the application instructions very carefully. Is it possible that the reason they keep demanding different documents from you is because you didn't read that part of the instructions very carefully, either?

Answer (score 5):

A visa permitting a five-year **stay** would be a residency permit. Questions about that should be asked at Expatriates Stack Exchange.

A multiple-entry, short-term visa could have five years **validity period**, but it would still only allow 90 days out of every 180 days in the Schengen area. These visa are usually granted only after several successful visits on shorter-validity visa.